# Use stream filter only if parameter is not null

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have classes:

```
public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int albumNo;
    private List<String> courses;
   ...
}

public class StudentList {
    private List<Student> students;

    public List<Student> filter(String course, String firstName) {
        return students
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getCourses().contains(course))
                .filter(s -> s.getFirsName().equals(firstName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

However there is a possibility, that parameters of filter function might be empty (as they are query parameters). Is there a way to use course and firstName filters only if function arguments aren't null? I know I could check if parameters aren't null before filtering, but then I would have to have different configuration of filtering for every occasion and I don't want that.

Comment: `.filter(s -> course == null || s.getCourses().contains(course))`

Comment: Can `getCourses()` actually contain null (or can `getFirsName()` be null)? If not, there's no need to do anything special.

Comment: well, even if getCourses() and getFirstName() can't return null, it IS a problem because filtering still will fail

Comment: According to me if `course` or `firstName` null, what is the point of stream and filtering ? you can simply avoid calling `filter` method if they are null, that might be recommended option by me

Comment: I've wrote about it in description. There actually can be more parameters. If I were to check every one of them separetly and have, as in this example, 4 configurations: both parameters are/aren't null, one of parameters is null that would be problmatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as below,

```
public List<Student> filter(String course, String firstName) {
    return students
            .stream()
            .filter(s-> filterStudent(s,course, firstName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private boolean filterStudent(Student s, String course, String firstName) {
  return (s.getCourses() == null || s.getCourses().contains(course) &&
            (s.getFirsName() == null || s.getFirsName().equals(firstName)));
}
```

Comment: Except, of course, you need to pass `course` and `firstName` to the `filterStudent` method.

Comment: Not required. We can pass `Student` object istself

Comment: Sure, you can pass the `Student`; but the `course` and `firstName` symbols aren't defined in the `filterStudent` method. https://ideone.com/NhhdwC

Comment: @AndyTurner, I got it. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing.